# Fundamental + verb

Tags: grammar

If the adjective **fundamental** is followed by a verb, should the **verb** be expressed in the **infinitive** or the **"ing" form**? Is the structure always the same when it comes to **fundamental + verb** or can it change depending on the sentence?

In my opinion, having similar characters isn't **fundamental to building / to build** a true friendship.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, we hear that verbs that come after adjectives are always in the infinitive form. It's a good general rule, but the usage of "fundamental" and similar adjectives can be confusing. As is normal with adjectives, it can be used with an infinitive after it:

> In any successful business venture, it's fundamental **to build** a strong social network.

Part of the grammar of "fundamental" is that you can use the *preposition* "to" to add the context where something is fundamental:

> Building a strong social network is fundamental **to any successful business venture**.

This can be confusing when the object of *preposition* "to" is a gerund, rather than a normal noun.

In your example, the negative will make my explanation confusing, so I'm going to change it to be positive:

> In my opinion, having similar characters **is** fundamental to building / to build a true friendship.

So, in your example. To choose between "to building" or "to build", you have to decide whether this sentence is saying "building friendships" is fundamental in some context (infinitive form), or "building friendships" is the context where something else is fundamental ("to" + gerund form).

I think you'll agree that "having similar characteristics" is the thing that's fundamental, and that "building a true friendship" is the context, so the correct answer is to your original example is to use preposition "to" + gerund:

> In my opinion, having similar characters isn't fundamental **to building** a true friendship.